# How to delete data with 2 parameters (WHERE...AND) in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a little problem, I want to delete data by 2 where conditions, maybe I did something wrong in my view

I try to delete data by `id_user` and `id_produk`

```
 //this is my view

<?php $rows = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM V_cart where id_user='".$this->session->id_user."'")->result_array();{?>
                                <?php foreach($rows as $cr):?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class=""><img style="width:100px;" src="<?= base_url('assets/images/produk/').$cr['foto'];?>" alt="product img"></a>
                                        <td class="product-name"><?= $cr['nama_produk'];?></td>
                                        <td class="product-price"><?= $cr['harga'];?></td>
                                        <td class="product-price"><?= $cr['ukuran'];?></span></td>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="harga" value="<?= $cr['harga'];?>">
                                        <td><input name="jumlah" type="number" min='1' value="<?= $cr['jumlah'];?>"> </td>       
                                        <td id="amount" class="product-subtotal"><?= $cr['total_harga'];?></td>    
                                        <td class=""><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>user/del_cart/<?=$id=$cr['id_produk'];?>" href="<?php echo base_url();?>user/del_cart/<?=$id=$this->session->id_user;?>"  name="submit" style="color:#fff;" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>         
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php endforeach;?>   
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </tbody>
```

//this is my controller

```
     public function del_cart($id){
           $where=array(['id_user'=>$id],['id_produk'=>$id]); var_dump($where);
           $this->M_admin->del_cart($where,'tbl_cart');
           $this->session->set_flashdata('notif','<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert"> <strong>Data Berhasil dihapus! </strong> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');
           redirect('user/cart');
        }
```

//and this is my model

```
function del_cart($where,$table){
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->delete($table);
}
```

I want to delete data by 2 parameters, `id_user` and `id_produk`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>user/del_cart/<?php echo $cr['id_produk'].'/'.$this->session->id_user;?>" style="color:#fff;" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Use the href tag once,Just pass the two parameters like this,if you are using session variable no need to pass from here, you can add this is you controller or model in where clause.Your controller code will be like

```
function del_cart($param1,$param2){
$where=array('table_col1'=>$param1,'table_col2'=>$param2);
$this -> Model_name -> del_cart($where,$table_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of correct syntaxes for delete is:

```
$this->db->delete($table, $where);
```

Where `$where` is **array** and not **array of arrays**.

So, the solution is:

```
function del_cart($where,$table){
    $this->db->delete($table, $where);
}
```

And calling:

```
$this->M_admin->del_cart(
    ['id_user' => $id, 'id_produk' => $id],
    'tbl_cart'
);
```